# Vector in java always overwriting everything with the last value

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I'm a beginner in java and I have the following exercise to solve:

Read a set of sports lottery bets to an unspecified number of players. After that, read the template, compare the result and display a message.

1. Bet Class: must contain the player's name and an integer vector with thirteen positions to store the bet: 1 – winner of team A, 2 – winner of team B, and 0 for draw. Create the necessary constructor methods and the toString method.
2. ReadBets Class: This class must have an attribute that is a vector of objects of the Bet class. In addition, this class must have a method to read the person's name and their sports lottery game. Create the necessary constructor methods and the toString method.
3. ReadTemplate Class: This class should read the correct answers from the sports lottery game and store the result in an integer vector. Create the necessary constructor methods and the toString method.
4. GenerateResult Class: this class must compare the players' bets with the result of the template and, if you have 6 correct answers, show the winner's name, his game and the message: “WINNER, CONGRATULATIONS”. Otherwise, show the player name and the message “Try again, this time you didn't win”.
5. Main Class: implement in this class the control and execution flow for this problem creating the necessary objects to solve this class.

There is a complicating factor for me which is that each object bet is composed of a string name with a vector with the bets.

I made a solution to the problem that already reads validating only the allowed values (0,1,2), reads the template and compares.

However, **I noticed that the last name typed and the last bets are always being recorded in the vector. In all positions.**

I'm hours assembling and disassembling the code and I can't find a way to solve it.

I read that it may have to do with the new but I didn't understand how to solve it because at each position of the vector of objects I need to give a new to create the object with the internal vector that will store that player's bets.

Below are my classes:

MAIN:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

public void execute(){}
static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
//ReadBet a = new ReadBet();

V_Bets a = new V_Bets();

System.out.println("Enter the total bets that will be placed");
a.totalBets(input.nextInt());

a.Data entry();
a.Data output();

ReadTemplate g = new ReadTemplate();
g.getTemplate();

GenerateResult gr = new GenerateResult();
gr.generateResult();
}

}
```

BETS:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bet {

private static String name;
public static int[] Bet vector =new int [6];

/*public String getName(){

         return this.name;
     }*/

public static String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
         this.name=name;
     }

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Bet [name=" + name + ",Betvector=" + Arrays.toString(Betvector) + "]";
}

public int getBet(int i) {
return this.vector Bets[i];
}

public void setBets(int[] bets) {
this.vector Bets = bets;
}

public int[] getCloneArray() {
         returnVectorBets.clone();
     }
}
```

V_BETS

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class V_Bets {

Input Scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

private int size;
public static Total BetBets[] = new Bet[100];


//total Bets[j] = new Bet(); //Creating a bet object for each registration - bet object contains name and bet vector of that bettor

private Bet bets = new Bet();
int i=0;
int j=0;

public void dataentry() {

for(j=0;j<size;j++) { //for external - from J that controls the total bets that will be registered
totalBets[j] = new Bet(); //Creating a bet object for each registration - bet object contains name and bet vector of that bettor

System.out.println("Enter the name of the Player:");
    totalStakes[j].setName(input.next()); //setting the player's name
    
    // loop to set the guesses
    System.out.println("Please enter guesses for each Sports Lottery game");
    System.out.println("1 - Winner Team A, 2 - Winner Team B and 0 - Tie");

    for ( i=0;i<bets.vetorApostas.length;i++) // receive the bet until it reaches 6
    {
    System.out.println("Game "+i +":");
    
    totalStakes[j].vectorStakes[i] = input.nextInt(); // receive the user's bets

    while (totalApostas[j].vectorApostas[i] < 0 ) // if the user enters a negative number it says to try again
    {
    System.err.println("Negative Number, try again:");
    totalBets[j].vectorBets[i]= entry.nextInt();
    }

    if (totalApostas[j].vetorApostas[i] > 2) // if the number is greater than 2 it says to try again
    {
    while (totalBets[j].vectorBets[i] > 2 ) {
    System.err.println("Please enter numbers between 0 and 2");
    totalBets[j].vectorBets[i]= entry.nextInt();
    }
    }
    }
    
}
}

/*public void dataoutput() {
//System.out.println("The player's name is:"+total Bets[i].getName());
System.out.println("Your Bet:");
for ( i=0;i < Bet.vectorBeats.length; i++){
System.out.print(+TotalStakes[i].vectorStakes[i].getStakes(i)+ " ");

}
}

public void dataoutput() {
System.out.println("Your Bet::");
for (j=0; j<totalBets[i].vectorBets.length; j++) {
System.err.print("Player "+Total Bets[j].getName()+" ");
for (i = 0; i < totalBets[i].vectorBets.length; i++) {
System.err.print(total Bets[j].vector Bets[i] + " ");
}
}
}*/

public void totalOfBets(int size) {
this.size = size;
}

public int getSize() {
return size;
}

}
```

TEMPLATE:

```
    public class Template {

//private String name;
public static int[]vectorTemplate =new int [6];

public int getBet(int i) {
return this.vectorTemplate[i];
}

public void setBets(int[] bets) {
this.vectorTemplate = bets;
}

public int getTemplate(int i) {
return this.vectorTemplate[i];
}

public void setTemplate(int[] bets) {
this.vectorTemplate = bets;
}
}
```

READ TEMPLATE:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadTemplate {

private Template template = new Template();

Input Scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

int guesses;
int counter=0;
int j;
int x;
int i;

public void getTemplate() {

System.out.println(" ");

for ( j=0;j<6;j++) // Receive numbers until it reaches 6
{
System.out.println("Now Enter Game Template: "+j);

template.vectorTemplate[j]= entry.nextInt(); // Receive user numbers
while (template.vetorTemplate[j] < 0 ) // If you enter a negative number, ask the user to type again
{
System.err.println("Negative Number, try again:");
template.vectorTemplate[j]=input.nextInt();
}

if (template.vectorTemplate[j] > 2) // if the number is greater than 2 ask again
{
while (template.vectorTemplate[j] > 2 )
{
System.err.println("Please enter numbers between 0 and 2");
template.vectorTemplate[j]=input.nextInt();
}
}
}

//printing the template
System.out.println("Template:");
for (i = 0; i < template.vectorTemplate.length; i++) {
System.out.print(template.vectorTemplate[i] + " ");
}

}

}
```

GENERATE RESULTS:

```
public class GenerateResult extends ReadTemplate {

private Bet bets = new Bet();
private Template template = new Template();
//private v_bets v_bets = new v_bets();
private int size;

public void generateResult() {
//Checking if it's right
int x;


V_Bets a = new V_Bets();


for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
int i=0;
int counter=0;

for (x = 0; x < template.vectorTemplate.length; x++) {
if (a.totalStakes[j].vectorStakes[i] == template.vectorTemplate[x]) {
counter++;
}
i++;
}

System.out.println(" ");


System.out.println("Counter of Equals! "+counter);

if (counter <= 5){

System.out.println("Player "+a.Total Bets[j].getName());
System.out.println("Try again, this time you won");
}

else if (counter == 6){
System.out.println("Player "+a.Total Bets[j].getName());
System.out.println("WINNER,CONGRATULATIONS!");
}
}
}

public void totalOfBets(int size) {
this.size = size;
}

}
```

I am immensely grateful to anyone who can help understand where I went wrong and how to evolve.

Comment: Don't make your member variables `static`. Because they are `static`, there is only one copy of the member variable that's shared by all instances of the class. See [A guide to the `static` keyword in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static)

Comment: Got it, read it, adjusted it and it worked.

Thank you very much for the support.